# ASP MVC "MetaData typeof and Required" wont't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, expression, metadata

I'am creating some kind of grid view using ADO.NET, without Entity framework. I cannot figure out why MetaData + Required and other expressions won't work. This is my sample code:

Business object Model class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ObslugaStonyLibrary
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(zmienneWczytywanieTresci))]
    public partial class zmienneWczytywanieTresciMeta
    {
        public class zmienneWczytywanieTresci
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public int druzynaID { get; set; }
            public string Druzyna { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public int LiczbaMeczy { get; set; }
            public string LiczbaGoliStrzelonych { get; set; }
            public string LiczbaGoliStraconych { get; set; }
        }
     }
}
```

Application model:

```
namespace Start.Models
{
    public class InformacjeModel
    {
        public IPagedList<zmienneWczytywanieTresciMeta.zmienneWczytywanieTresci> tabela { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form, int? page)
    {
        zmienneWczytywanieTresciMeta.zmienneWczytywanieTresci zmienne = new zmienneWczytywanieTresciMeta.zmienneWczytywanieTresci();
        zmienne.LiczbaMeczy = Convert.ToInt32(form["LiczbaMeczy"]);

        int ID = Convert.ToInt32(form["news.ID"]);
        var model = new InformacjeModel();

        string queryWczytaj = "Select * From LigaMistrzowGrupy Where Grupa = @Grupa";
        string queryUpdate = "Update LigaMistrzowGrupy Set LiczbaMeczy = @LiczbaMeczy Where ID = @ID";

        funkcjeWczytywanieTresci wczytywanie = new funkcjeWczytywanieTresci();
        wczytywanie.edytujTabele(queryUpdate, zmienne, ID);

        model.tabela = funkcjeWczytywanieTresci.wczytajTabele(queryWczytaj, "A").ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 4);

        return View(model);
    }
```

And view:

```
@foreach (var news in Model.tabela)
    {   
        using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <div class="ramkaTRgridView">
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => news.ID, "ID");
                <button type="submit" class="floatDivGridView">Submit</button>
                <div class="ramkaTDgridViewID floatDivGridView">
                    <span>@Html.Label(news.druzynaID.ToString())</span>
                </div>
                <div class="ramkaTDgridViewDruzyna floatDivGridView">
                    <span>@Html.Label(news.Druzyna.ToString())</span>
                </div>
                <div class="ramkaTDgridViewStatystyki floatDivGridView">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => news.LiczbaMeczy, "LiczbaMeczy", "LiczbaMeczy");
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => news.LiczbaMeczy)
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    }
```

Everything else works fine, except validation. Could You help me ?

Comment: Why do you need Metadata classes if you're not using EF?

Comment: I was following with a tutorial, and there was Metadata. But after that i done this on my own way without Metadata and any tutorials, and now works fine ;).

Answer (score 2):

That isn't the way it works.  You would normally do it like this (note that you put the MetadateType attribute on the class you want to have metadata, not on the Metadata class itself)

```
public partial class A
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(AMeta))]
public partial class A
{
}

public class AMeta
{
    [Required]
    public int ID {get;set;}
}
```

Some people like to nest the Metadata class within the extended partial, since you would never really need to reference the Metadata class yourself.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(A.AMeta))]
public partial class A
{
    public class AMeta
    {
        [Required]
        public int ID {get;set;}
    }    
}
```